# How to add/upload the static files into specific path of the Azure Blob Storage Container

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I have developed the following PowerShell script for to create the folders inside the Azure Blob Storage Container.

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
  [string]
  $resourceGroupName,

  [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
  [string]
  $storageAccountName
)

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AccountName $storageAccountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
$dirs = @('ABC', 'XYZ', 'ABC123', 'XYZ123')
$subdirs = @('Archive', 'Logs')
Foreach ($d in $dirs) {
  ForEach ($s in $subdirs) {
    New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $d/$s -Directory
  }
}
```

I want to add/upload `.xml` files into specific folder path (`ABC123/Logs`) of Azure Blob Storage Container.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide details about the issues you are running into with your script.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following script to upload a file to a directory by using the `New-AzDataLakeGen2Item cmdlet.

Reference documentation: [Upload a file to a directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-powershell#upload-a-file-to-a-directory)

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
  [string]
  $resourceGroupName,

  [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
  [string]
  $storageAccountName,
   
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
  [string]
  $filesystemName,

  [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
  [string]
  $localSrcFilesPath
)

Write-Host "Starting to create the directory references...."

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AccountName $storageAccountName

$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

$dirs = @('ABC', 'XYZ')
$subdirs = @('Archive', 'Logs')

Foreach ($d in $dirs) {

  ForEach ($s in $subdirs) {

    New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $d/$s -Directory

    $files= Get-ChildItem $localSrcFilesPath

    foreach($file in $files){

        $localSrcFile =  "$localSrcFilesPath\$file"
        $destPath = "$d/$s/$file"

        if("$d/$s" -eq 'ABC/Logs'){

            Write-Host "Starting to upload file: "$destPath

            New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $destPath -Source $localSrcFile -Force
            
            Write-Host "Completed to upload file:" $destPath "into Azure Storage Blob Container"

        }
    }

  }
}

Write-Host "Completed to create the directory references"
```